# Using .environmentObject with a View presented as a sheet causes onReceive not to fire/conflicts with @EnvironmentObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my `ContentView`, I have a button that does a simple `sheet` present of my `SettingsView`.  There seems to be some conflict with my `@EnvironmentObject var iconSettings: IconNames` in `SettingsView` when the view is presented modally where my `onReceive` function only fires when the view loads the first time and never when the `Picker` is used.

Looking around for answers related to this, I was only able to find something related to CoreData which wasn't really helpful but I'm sure others have experienced this, so would be great to have something canonical and more general for others to reference.

Thanks!

```
Button(action: { self.modalDisplayed = true }) {
   Assets.gear
}.sheet(isPresented: $modalDisplayed) {
   SettingsView(state: self.state, loadCards: self.load)
      .environmentObject(IconNames())
}
```

Then in my SettingsView, I have the following:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var state: AppState

    @EnvironmentObject var iconSettings: IconNames

    let loadCards: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $iconSettings.currentIndex) {
                ForEach(Publication.allCases, id: \.pubId) {
                    Text($0.pubName).tag($0.pubId)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding(20)
            Spacer()
        }
        .onReceive([self.iconSettings.currentIndex].publisher.first()) { value in
            print(value) // only hits on first load, never on tap
            print("")
            let index = self.iconSettings.iconNames.firstIndex(of: UIApplication.shared.alternateIconName) ?? 0
            if index != value { UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(self.iconSettings.iconNames[value]) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        print("Success!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my IconNames class:

```
class IconNames: ObservableObject {
    var iconNames: [String?] = [nil]
    @Published var currentIndex = 0

    init() {
        getAlternateIconNames()

        if let currentIcon = UIApplication.shared.alternateIconName {
            self.currentIndex = iconNames.firstIndex(of: currentIcon) ?? 0
        }
    }

    func getAlternateIconNames() {
        if let icons = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleIcons") as? [String: Any],
            let alternateIcons = icons["CFBundleAlternateIcons"] as? [String: Any]
        {

             for (_, value) in alternateIcons{

                 guard let iconList = value as? Dictionary<String,Any> else{return}
                 guard let iconFiles = iconList["CFBundleIconFiles"] as? [String]
                     else{return}

                 guard let icon = iconFiles.first else{return}
                 iconNames.append(icon)
             }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as provided code snapshot is not testable by copy-paste, so only by code reading, try instead of

```
.onReceive([self.iconSettings.currentIndex].publisher.first()) { value in
```

use this one

```
.onReceive(self.iconSettings.$currentIndex) { value in
```